# Animating circles, based on ODE-solver output in Matlab

Tags: matlab, animation, matlab-figure, ode45

I am new to Matlab and am trying to animate several spheres moving along a straight line based on both, initial speed and position.

I have gotten the ode45 solver to spit out velocity and displacement plots for me (over time) and would now like to 2D-animate circles over a 15 second time interval that change position based on the output of the ODE Solver.

Function:

```
function rt = odes(t,x)

k = 0.9;     %Friction Konstant
m =1;        %Mass Konstant

rt(1) = (-k*x(1))/m ;   % Acceleration   
rt(2) = x(1);           % x-component Velocity
rt(3) = 0;              % z-component Velocity

rt = rt(:);
```

Code of actual program:

```
cla
clc
clear all
close all

%Define constants and initial conditions

speedvar = 0.08 ; %Slows down animation
t = 0;
t_end = 15;
d = 1;
a = 1
radii = d/2;

v1_0 = 1;   %Initial Velocities
v2_0 = 2;

x1_0 = 0;   %Initial absolute positions x-axys
x2_0 = a+d;

z0 = 0; %Initial absolute position z-axys

IC1 = [v1_0;x1_0;z0];       %Initial Conditions
IC2 = [v2_0;x2_0;z0];
timerange = [t t_end ];     %Define Timerange

%Call ode45 for each ball and plot absolute x-position & Velocity over time
[t,x1] = ode45(@(t,x)odes(t,x),timerange,IC1);
figure 
plot (t,x1(:,1))
xlabel ('Time in s')
ylabel ('Velocity in m/s')
figure
plot (t,x1(:,2))
xlabel ('Time in s')
ylabel ('Position x-axys')

[t,x2] = ode45(@(t,x)odes(t,x),timerange,IC2);
figure 
plot (t,x2(:,1))
xlabel ('Time in s')
ylabel ('Velocity in m/s')
figure
plot (t,x2(:,2))
xlabel ('Time in s')
ylabel ('Position x-axys')

%// Animate 
for id = 1:length(t)
    cla
    axis square
    xlim([-1.1 10*x1(2)])
    ylim([-x1(2)*5 x1(2)*5])

    center1 = [x1(id,2) z0];
    center2 = [x2(id,2) z0];

    hc1 = viscircles(center1,radii);
    hc2 = viscircles(center2,radii);
    pause(speedvar) %slow down animation according to speedvar

end
```

However, when I run the code the circle movements aren't taking place at the the same time. It seems like the program is solving for x2 first, animating it and then repeating the process for x1. How can I get them to solve/animate parallel to each other?

Comment: @m7913d I have edited the post to differntiate what I'm asking from your suggested post

Comment: I do not see the difference from the duplicate. You should (1) plot the circle again in every loop using the new center and (2) pause the execution each time after a draw.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem thanks to your help (thank you so much!), but have now found that when I try animating several circles their animation doesn't happen at the same time, but rather one after the other. I will again edit my question and adapt it to this new issue.

Comment: The problem is that the time vectors of both ode solutions are not the same. You need to resample/interpolate it to the same (uniform) time vector.